# PO file Gettext not working. Not reading po file translation

Tags: php

I need to translate my web to french but it's not translating. I did a lot of changes on the code but nothing seems to work. Any idea?

```
<?php
    $langSite = 'fr';
    
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $langSite);
    putenv("LANGUAGE=".$langSite);
    
    $langDomain = 'fr';
    bindtextdomain($langDomain, 'lang');
    
    bind_textdomain_codeset($langDomain, 'UTF-8');
    
    textdomain($langDomain);

    echo _("Password"); // returning Password instead of Mot de passe
?>
```

My fr.po file found at langs/fr/LC_MESSAGES looks like this:

```
msgctxt "Password"
msgid "Password"
msgstr "Mot de passe"
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.) You have to create a compiled version  with ending  .mo  from the .po file and put this on the server.**

This can be done e.g. with Poedit
https://poedit.net/

POEDIT is VERY NICE - it scans the complete directory for all files and puts all translation strings into the .po file and offers a GUI for doing it with checks and more.  The paid ( one-time) version is even better  it can use web services to translate your strings if you translate from your language to foreign languages.

**2.) Remark:**
Usually your domain is only e.g. 'messages' and the gettext then uses the correct directory for the desired language.
The filenames are then messages.po and messages.mo

I had a hard time getting it started as I also used en.po until checking that the file name must be the same as the domain.

**3.) here is the code in my includefile to configute GETTEXT on my server:**
(before i have some checks if the language came from SESSION or GET but that is a different story.)

```
putenv ( "LANG=" . $language );
setlocale (LC_ALL, $language.".UTF8" );

// Set the text domain as "messages"
$domain = "messages";
$domain_path= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/locale";
bindtextdomain($domain, $domain_path);
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, "UTF-8" );
textdomain($domain);
```

The values up there reflect my path structure:

this is

```
/locale/
        /{language}/
                    LC_MESSAGES/
                                messages.po
                                messages.mo
```

**4. you write**

> bindtextdomain($langDomain, **'lang'**);
>
> My fr.po file found at **langs** /fr/LC_MESSAGES looks like this:

The second parameter for binddextdomain must be the same as the path but you have either a typo or another error   because you have once **lang** and the other time **langs** ??
This must be the same!